# How to read variable from application.yml with spring boot and use it in kotlin test

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, yaml

```
src
  main
    java
       config
          DataSourceProperties.java
    resources
      application.yml
  test
    kotlin
      service
          AuthService.kt
```

1. I have application.yml 
   [Image of application.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItspI.png)
2. I have java configure class

   ```
    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
   class DataSourceProperties {
      private String apiUrl;
      public String getApiUrl() { return apiUrl; }
      public void setUrl(String apiUrl) {
         this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
   }
   ```
3. I have service kotlin class

   ```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
    @SpringBootApplication
    @Profile("dev")
    class AuthService {
      @Value("\${datasource.apiUrl}")
      lateinit var apiUrl: String
      fun registerUser(user: RequestUser): ErrorResponse {
       return given()
               .log().all()
               .body(user)
               .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
               .`when`().post("$apiUrl/security")
               .then().statusCode(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST)
               .extract()
               .`as`(ErrorResponse::class.java)
       }
   }
   ```

When I perform request in my test I get

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property apiUrl has not been initialized

That's why i have question? How can I use properties from yml file in test class. Maybe I miss another config, maybe I am not right with annotations, or maybe it depends from location of configure, yml and test files in structure. Please give me a hint.

Comment: Investigate some materials: 
I can launch java test class if it located in main folder. but when I relocate test class to test folder it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try set simply e.g. should help -
`@TestPropertySource(properties = ["spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth: false",
  "spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable: false"])`